# How to use unicode in Android resource?

Tags: android, unicode, utf-8, surrogate-pairs

I want to use [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4e1/index.htm) unicode character in my resource file.

But whatever I do, I end with dalvikvm crash (tested with Android 2.3 and 4.2.2):

```
W/dalvikvm( 8797): JNI WARNING: input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte 0xf0
W/dalvikvm( 8797):              string: ''
W/dalvikvm( 8797):              in Landroid/content/res/StringBlock;.nativeGetString:(II)Ljava/lang/String; (NewStringUTF)
E/dalvikvm( 8797): VM aborting
F/libc    ( 8797): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 8797 (cz.ipex...)
```

I tried these version in my resource file:

```xml
<string name="geolocation_icon" translatable="false">&#x1f4e1;</string> <!-- HTML -->
<string name="geolocation_icon" translatable="false">\uD83D\uDCE1</string> <!-- escaped unicode -->
<string name="geolocation_icon" translatable="false"></string> <!-- unicode character -->
```

Note that using it in Java String in code works ok:

```java
final String geolocation_icon = "\uD83D\uDCE1";
```

Comment: Did you try to use UTF-8 in your XML file? Using hexdump, can you confirm that it is encoded as `0xF0 0x9F 0x93 0xA1` sequence?

Comment: Yes, it is, and if you look at the error output above, you see it is complaining about it:  `input is not valid Modified UTF-8: illegal start byte 0xf0`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Your character (`U+1F4E1`) is outside of Unicode BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane - range from `U+0000` to `U+FFFF`).

Unfortunately, Android has very weak (if any) support for non-BMP characters. `UTF-8` representation for non-BMP characters requires 4 bytes (`0xF0 0x9F 0x93 0xA1`). But, Android `UTF-8` parser only understands 3 bytes maximum (see it **[here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/refs/heads/oreo-release/libdex/DexUtf.h#46)** and **[here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/refs/heads/oreo-release/libdex/DexSwapVerify.cpp#1984)**).

It works for you when you use `UTF-16` surrogate form representation of this character: `"\uD83D\uDCE1"`. If you were able to encode each surrogate `UTF-16` character in modified `UTF-8` (aka `CESU-8`) - it would take 6 bytes total (3 bytes in `UTF-8` for each member of surrogate pair), then it would be possible. But, Android does not support `CESU-8` explicitly either.

So, your current solution - hard-coding this symbol in source code as surrogate `UTF-16` pair seems easiest, at least until Android starts fully supporting non-BMP `UTF-8`.

**UPDATE**: this seems to be partially fixed in Android 6.0. [This commit](https://android-review.googlesource.com/130121) has been merged into Android 6, and permits presence of 4-byte UTF-8 characters in XML resources. Its not perfect solution - it will simply automatically convert 4-byte UTF-8 into appropriate surrogate pair. However, it allows to move them from your source code into XML resources. Unfortunately, you can't use this solution until your application can stop supporting any Android version except for 6.0 and later.

Comment: This is very frustrating as it makes the Class file much larger than it needs to be.  It would be ideal to separate these unicode strings into an `arrays.xml` or `strings.xml` file.

Comment: @toobsco42: you might want to [file a bug](http://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html) in [Android bug database](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues).

Comment: hi, i have an xml file with surrogate pairs like "\uD83D\uDCE1" but i'm getting errors when trying to parse the file, could you help me ?

Comment: @SWAppDev: you can use surrogate pairs in Java source code, but not in resource XML.

Comment: This [website](http://www.russellcottrell.com/greek/utilities/surrogatepaircalculator.htm) lets you calculate the surrogate pairs.

Comment: I use it on a menu and it still doesn't work from strings.xml,,nor from the menu xml file.  I have to put it in Java source code and reset the menu.  On Android 9

Answer (score 0):

**Do it this way**

Do not keep problematic emoji in the strings.xml

add it programmatically

```
<string name="hi_welcome_msg">Hi %1$s</string>

getString(R.string.hi_welcome_msg, user.getFullName() + " \uD83D\uDC4B" );
```