# Unicode Characters for Hindi in android

Tags: java, android, unicode

I have to do my application in English and Hindi, after the translation i have to send the content through email. For hindi language translation I used Localization and i added .ttf files to my assets/fonts folder. By using Localization lower version of android devices shows square boxes, using ttf files i am setting the text type face to textviews, it is rendering hindi letters.But when i am sending the mail Hindi font convert into english. at last i found Unicode characters for hindi language,but i dont know how to do If anybody know about this Unicode characters is that satisfies my requirement, if you have any example or any reference for that please please give me.

My requirement is Translate the English content into hindi and that content should be sent through email in hindi language.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786739/how-to-use-unicode-in-android-resource).