# Stop converting UTF-16 escape literals to the actual character in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, unicode, utf-16

To keep code clean across different platforms (and due to a bug where one can't use Unicode escape literals like `&#x1f601;` in XML files), instead of putting actual "non-normal" Unicode characters like U+1F601 (), I usually use `\u`-escaped UTF-16 surrogate pairs like `\ud83d\ude01`.

However, when I select and copy String literals containing these escapes from a Java source code file, they are converted to the actual character upon pasting. So when I copy and paste the text

```
String smile = "\ud83d\ude01";
```

to another location, it comes out as

```
String smile = "";
```

How can I disable this behavior? I didn't find anything in the Settings; or I searched in the wrong place.

Comment: That is JAVA, right? Those two lines by definition have exactly the same meaning. Are you storing that source code in an XML file?

Comment: No it's a java source code file. Why would I store Java code in an XML? I know they have the same meaning for the compiler/the JVM, but I don't want the IDE to convert the escape sequences.

Comment: Fair enough, but then using `\u` escapes doesn't work around any bugs involving putting characters in XML. I think it is safe, even across different platforms, to use a literal `""``, as long as you consistently encode source files as UTF-8 or UTF-16 (and set up that encoding in your project / encoding settings). For XML, encode it as UTF-8 and also just use a literal . I don't know why the IDE would *auto-convert* those escapes though, or how to switch it off.

Comment: No, I can't paste it in the XML. Due to a strange implementation on UTF-8 XML parsing, the app compiles but crashes when loading the layout file on pre-Marshmallow, i.e. at least 90% of the devices: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16789981/2033332

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not found an option that disables it when pasting; instead, I use the "Paste Simple" option to prevent the escaped Unicode from converting to the actual character.

On a Mac, the keyboard combination for "Paste Simple" is <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>