# I'm getting resource string error from play store?

Tags: android, android-studio, upload, apk, google-play-console

[image: **I'm trying to upload my app in playstore but I'm grtting your APK or Android App Bundle contains a string resource with name array/newline_values and configuration (default) that has an unescaped new line. Please use \ to express newlines in your resource definition. issue**]

I'm trying to upload my app in playstore but I'm grtting your APK or Android App Bundle contains a string resource with name array/newline_values and configuration (default) that has an unescaped new line. Please use \ to express newlines in your resource definition. issue
 \u000a \u000d\u000a   this is my array whats the issue in this

Comment: Please state your question more clearly. I think the play store error message is pretty clear. You need to fix the string value `newline_values` in one of your string resource files (probably `strings.xml`).

Comment: <string-array name="newline_values">
        <item>\u000a</item>
        <item>\u000d\u000a</item>
    </string-array> thanks for your rpl this is my array whats the issue in this

Comment: can this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786739/how-to-use-unicode-in-android-resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

- `\r` for carriage return instead of `\u000A`
- `\n` for line feed  instead of `\u000D`